# fetch a discord link from a long text

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
૮₍ • ᴥ • ₎ა・Raiden ▬▭⋱
ᘏ⑅ᘏ╭╯Welcome╰╮ᘏᗢ
・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・
https://discord.gg/rsCC8y7WC4
・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・
Join!
・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・
```

How can I pull the "discord.gg/rsCC8y7WC4" link from a text like this

```
console.log(invitelink) ==> discord.gg/rsCC8y7WC4
```

Comment: Have you heard of regular expressions before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for this. String.match accepts a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) argument which looks like this:

```js
let str = 'hey there this is just a random string';
let res = str.match(/random/);
//res is now ['random']
```

Now for your problem, you are probably looking for this:

```js
if(msg.content.match(/discord\.gg\/.+/) || msg.content.match(/discordapp\.com\/invite\/.+/)) return msg.channel.send('Hey! You put an invite in your message!');
```

Now that regex may look a bit messy/complicated but the \s are to escape the character and make sure regex knows that it’s not the special character it uses, and is actually just a character part of the search. To clarify why the above example should work, here’s a little explanation:
`match()` returns either an array (if it gets a match) or null (if it gets no match). You are searching for the strings `'discord.gg/'` followed by any characters and also checking for the string `'discordapp.com/invite/'` also followed by any characters.

If this doesn’t work, please tell me.